# XML processing using SAX parser in Storm

Tags: xml, saxparser, apache-storm

I am new to Storm. I need some source code please do help me. I am using Storm. I want to process this XML data using SAX parser as follows: Spout has to get this XML file and it will give input to the separate bolt as  from `<employee id =1>` to `</employee>`. Each bolt contains input as different employee details such as `bolt1=<employee id=1>` to `</employee>`, `bolt2=<employee id =2>` to `</employee>` and store the each input of the bolt into another XML file. The XML file name must be ìd` of the employee. Can you please give some sample code for us?

This is my XML file

```
<Employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Java Developer</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <age>35</age>
        <name>Lisa</name>
        <gender>Female</gender>
        <role>CEO</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="3">
        <age>40</age>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Manager</role>
    </Employee>
  </Employees>
```

Comment: Actually, your question is mainly about XML parsing. Read a couple of tutorials about that.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.Can you please sent the link of the tutorial?